# Html table in wrong order with ruby

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a simple table in a html.erb file with rails. However, the the output on the html page is in the wrong order.

This is the code from a helper for the view:

```
html_string = ""

if empl.gender == "M"
  gender = "Male"
else
  gender = "Female"
end

html_string << "<h1>" + empl.first_name + " " + empl.last_name + "</h1>
               <br><br>
               <table class = \"table2\">
               <tr><td>Employee number:</td><td>" + empl.emp_no.to_s + "</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Gender:</td></tr>" + gender + "</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Birth date</td><td>" + empl.birth_date.to_s + "</td></tr> 
               </table>"
```

I don't know if this is a conventional way to do it, but it works. The view itself just puts out the html string.

This is the page source from the web page:

```
                   <br><br>
                   <table class = "table2">
                   <tr><td>Employee number:</td><td>10005</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Gender:</td></tr>Male</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Birth date</td><td>1955-01-21</td></tr> 
                   </table>
```

Which seems to be in order, but it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N4bF.png)

Where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML string you have not opened `td` for the gender:

```
html_string << "<h1>" + empl.first_name + " " + empl.last_name + "</h1>
               <br><br>
               <table class = \"table2\">
               <tr><td>Employee number:</td><td>" + empl.emp_no.to_s + "</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Gender:</td><td>" + gender + "</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Birth date</td><td>" + empl.birth_date.to_s + "</td></tr> 
               </table>"
```

So in your version it is like this:

```
<tr><td>Gender:</td></tr>" + gender + "</td></tr>
```

which should be like this:

```
<tr><td>Gender:</td><td>" + gender + "</td></tr>
```

which should fix your issue.

Comment: Wow, suddenly I feel very stupid. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: You can accept any answer which helped you and which you feel is the best if your problem has been resolved.

Comment: @Gwobbel Refer this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - You wrote `</tr>` instead of `<td>`

```
html_string << "<h1>" + empl.first_name + " " + empl.last_name + "</h1>
               <br><br>
               <table class = \"table2\">
               <tr><td>Employee number:</td><td>" + empl.emp_no.to_s + "</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Gender:</td><td>" + gender + "</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Birth date</td><td>" + empl.birth_date.to_s + "</td></tr> 
               </table>"
```

The problem was in following line -

```
<tr><td>Gender:</td></tr>" + gender + "</td></tr>
```

It should be like this -

```
<tr><td>Gender:</td><td>" + gender + "</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using string to create your html markup, there are better options like creating an erb file instead.

But you can do it like so & choose string interpolation instead of those clumsy `+` symbols. This definitely increases readability and lead to less errors.

```
html_string = <<html
  <h1>#{empl.first_name} #{empl.last_name}</h1>
  <br><br>
  <table class ="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>Employee number:</td>
      <td>#{empl.emp_no.to_s}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gender:</td>
      <td>#{empl.gender == "M" ? "Male" : "Female"}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Birth date</td>
      <td>#{empl.birth_date.to_s}</td>
    </tr> 
  </table>
html
```